# Use of unresolved identifier NSSecondCalendarUnit in Swift

Tags: swift

I try to fetch hours minutes from current date:

```
var date:NSDate = NSDate()
        var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(unitFlags: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
        var hour = components.hour
        var minute = components.minute
        var seconds = components.second
```

However it doesn't recognize Calendar Units:

```
NSHourCalendarUnit, NSMinuteCalendarUnit andNSSecondCalendarUnit
```

I get error:

```
use of unresolved identifier NSSecondCalendarUnit ...
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSCalendarUnit` constants instead

```
var date:NSDate = NSDate()
        var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(
            NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
        var hour = components.hour
        var minute = components.minute
        var seconds = components.second
```

---

*Reference:*

From `NSCalendar` class

```
func components(unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit, fromDate date: NSDate!) -> NSDateComponents!
                             ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: With Swift 2.0 you have to use the following syntax for line #3 above:
var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)